# Reading from text file to display to multiple contacts

Tags: c++, xml, loops

I have to read from a file named "address.xml" which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<address_book>
    <contact>
        <name>George Clooney</name>
        <street>1042 El Camino Real</street>
        <city>Beverly Hills</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90214</zip>
       </contact>
```

and so on with multiple contacts. Needing to display only those with the city Palmdale. I've defined each element of the contact but when I try to display the ones in Palmdale, it only lists one contact (the last in the text doc). Do I need to use a loop to display all of them?

```
void test2() {
    ifstream fin;
    string row, name, street, city, state, zip;
    int start, end;
    fin.open("address.xml");
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "There was an error opening the file...";
        exit(1);
    }

while (getline(fin, row)) {

    if ((start = row.find("<name>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</name>");
        name = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<street>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</street>");
        street = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<city>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</city>");
        city = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<state>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</state>");
        state = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<zip>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</zip>");
        zip = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
}

if (city == "Palmdale") {
    cout << name << endl << street << endl
        << city << endl << state << endl << zip << endl;
}
fin.close();
}
```

Appreciate all who can point me in the right direction

Comment: Seems to me that you are iterating over the entire file and overwriting the name/street/city/state/zip addresses every time before printing only at the very end. If you put your if condition inside the while loop it may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if (city == "Palmdale") {...}` isn't in any loop, so it's only going to be run once, after all the data has been processed. Instead you should run it every time you got all the data. For instance, if you're sure that your schema is going to stay exactly this way, you can assume that your record is complete when you read the `<zip>` element. Or better yet, when the `<contact>` element closes. Try this:

```
while (getline(fin, row)) {

    if ((start = row.find("<name>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</name>");
        name = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<street>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</street>");
        street = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<city>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</city>");
        city = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<state>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</state>");
        state = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((start = row.find("<zip>")) != string::npos) {
        start = row.find(">");
        end = row.find("</zip>");
        zip = row.substr(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    }
    if ((row.find("</contact>")) != string::npos) {
        if (city == "Palmdale") {
            cout << name << endl << street << endl
            << city << endl << state << endl << zip << endl;
        }
    }
}


fin.close();
}
```

If it's getting any more complicated than this, I would really recommend using an XML library instead. Actually, I'd already use one for this task if you had to redo it.

---

Here's how it could look like using [tinyxml](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2), for instance (all you need is to add the `tinyxml2.h` and `tinyxml2.cpp` to the project):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include "tinyxml2.cpp"

int main() {
    tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile("address.xml");
    tinyxml2::XMLElement* book = doc.FirstChildElement("address_book");

    for (tinyxml2::XMLElement* contact = book->FirstChildElement("contact");
        contact != NULL; contact = contact->NextSiblingElement())
    {
        std::string name = contact->FirstChildElement("name")->GetText();
        std::string street = contact->FirstChildElement("street")->GetText();
        std::string city = contact->FirstChildElement("city")->GetText();
        std::string state = contact->FirstChildElement("state")->GetText();
        std::string zip = contact->FirstChildElement("zip")->GetText();

        if (city == "Palmdale") {
            std::cout << name << std::endl << street << std::endl
                << city << std::endl << state << std::endl << zip << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not affiliated with tinyxml, but used it in the past.

Comment: when row.find("</contact>") how is it being stored for each record?

Comment: You are storing the `name` and so with your other `if ((start = row.find(` calls and assume that all the fields will be read in once it hits the `</contact>`. At this point, it prints them all (if the `city` is `Palmdale`). Then the `if ((start = row.find(` for the next `contact` element will overwrite the strings again.

Answer (score 1):

1. the `if (city == "Palmdale") {...}` is applied only for the last record. You need to print inside the loop.
2. You better use XML parser library, since your program may fail for legit XMLs.

   - It not discarding leading and trailing spaces
   - It assume no line breaks between start tag, value and end tag.
   - It referring to lines without their context, not as `contact` nodes, for example, if you omit city from one element, it will use the previous element's city.